# All my semi-colons are throwing errors CS1002 and CS1056

Tags: c#, syntax

A project I've been working on for quite some times now throws those 2 errors on almost every semi-colons I have :

- [CS1002](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1002) : ";" expected
- [CS1056](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1056) : Unexpected character ";"

Yesterday when I left my office the project was building and running correctly, but today when I opened it I have been violently assaulted by more than 600 compilation errors. When I replace each semi-colon manually the 2 errors disappear, but i can't find them with Ctrl+F.

Here is a sample of my code with errors :

```cs
ignoredPropertiesName = ignoredPropertiesName ?? Array.Empty<string>();  // Replaced manually, doesn't thow any error

foreach (PropertyInfo property in objToCompare1.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (!ignoredPropertiesName.Contains(property.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (!property.GetValue(objInMemory).Equals(property.GetValue(objFromDb)))
        {
            return false;  // Not replaced, throws errors CS1002 and CS1056
        }
    }
}

return true;  // Not replaced, throws errors CS1002 and CS1056
```

I know what those errors mean, but I have no idea why this is happening. Does anyone have any idea? I kinda don't want to replace manually more than 300 semi-colons

Comment: "Can't find them with Ctrl-F" - how are you doing that - by typing the character into the search box, or are you copying one of the suspect characters into it? Because it's highly suggestive that someone's replaced the characters with another character which resembles a semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone has (maliciously/mischeviously?) replaced your semicolons with [Greek question marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Greek_question_mark) :

> U+037E ; GREEK QUESTION MARK

Lock your computer when you leave your desk and/or review your version control history or policies.

Comment: Or don't allow your colleagues to merge code to Version Control that doesn't compile.

Comment: Yeah a friend at the office confessed he cracked my password and replaced almost all semi-colons and shut off again my pc, I swear I'm gonna lock my pc in a locker when i'm off work!

Comment: @Error404Brainnotfound You might rather sternly let this friend know that behaviour like that can get you fired in a lot of places.  It's time to grow up.

Comment: He knows don't worry but we're in a small start-up so everyone is friendly here, no harm done to anyone just a joke :)

Comment: @Error404Brainnotfound Yeah, it's all fun and games until you're [telling it to the judge](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2532596/snooping-into-a-co-worker-s-e-mail--you-could-be-arrested.html).  Hacking into a coworker's computer is a serious crime, no matter how much of a joke you might think it is.  It's a simple matter of good fortune that the outcome was not serious in this case.  It won't always be so.  These schoolyard shenanigans can get you into serious trouble - it's time to leave them behind.

Comment: `Yeah a friend at the office confessed he cracked my password` - that's not a _friend_, that's a bad colleage _sabotaging_ you and the company.. talk to your manager about that. doing sth. like this on an unlocked computer - as educational measure - is okay-ish. but cracking a password to do this is unacceptable... as is, obviously, the weakness of your password. if your friend can crack it, so can any malicious attacker.

Comment: Okay I'll think more seriously about that tank you guys for your recommandations